# How to create a multisite from an existing Drupal site

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I have an existing drupal 7 site that we want to convert into a multi site.  I want the new database to have the same content structure as the existing site.  What would be the steps I have to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Acquia dev desktop , you can click on "More" at the bottom and create a multisite from an existing site.  Other wise I also found this https://www.drupal.org/project/multisite_wizard